# How to graph a times series tibble by decade

Tags: r, indexing, time-series

I'm taking an online class on how to use RStudio, which came with its own exercise files that I look at while I follow along with the class videos. The exercise files are identical to the ones that are shown in these videos, but for some odd reason, I'm getting an error that reads:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `decade = f(date)`.
Caused by error in `unsupported_date_time()`:
! Unsupported date-time class 'yearmonth' Unsupported date-time class 'vctrs_vctr'

Based on the error, it seems that there is something wrong with the portion that reads:

`index_by(                             decade = ~ floor_date(tidy_ts$date, years(10)) )`

but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the code in context:

```
# Install pacman ("package manager") if needed
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")

pacman::p_load(datasets, pacman, tidyverse, tsibble, 
    lubridate, XML)

# Tidy the data
tidy_ts <- sunspots %>%  
  as_tsibble() %>%        # Convert to timeseries tibble
  mutate(                 # Create new variables
    year = year(index),   # Create a year column
    month = month(index)  # Create a month column
  ) %>%
    select(                 # Select, reorder, rename vars
        date = index,         # Rename "index" to "date"
        year,                 # Use "year" as second variable
        month,                # Use "month" as third variable
        spots = value         # Rename "value" as "spots"
    ) %>%
    print()                 # Show data

# Graph the tidy data by decade
tidy_ts %>%
  index_by(                            # By decade
    decade = ~ floor_date(tidy_ts$date, years(10))
  ) %>%
  summarise(mean_s = mean(spots)) %>%  # Mean for decade
  ggplot(aes(decade, mean_s)) +        # Plot means
  geom_point() +                       # Scatterplot
  geom_smooth() +                      # Smoother
  ylab("Sunspots: Mean by Decade")     # Label
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`floor_date` can't be used on a `yearmonth` object.

One way we can get decade summaries is to floor it ourselves.
Since `yearmonth`s basically count the number of months since epoch (1st Jan 1970),
we can simply floor it to the nearest (12 months * 10 years).

```
tidy_ts %>%
  mutate(decade_start = floor(as.double(date) / 120) * 120) %>%
  mutate(decade_start = yearmonth(decade_start)) %>%
  index_by(decade = decade_start) %>%
  summarise(mean_s = mean(spots)) %>%  # Mean for decade
  ggplot(aes(decade, mean_s)) +        # Plot means
  geom_point() +                       # Scatterplot
  geom_smooth() +                      # Smoother
  ylab("Sunspots: Mean by Decade")     # Label
)
```

[image]

Another method is to convert the yearmonth to a date and then floor that.

```
tidy_ts %>%
  mutate(month_start = origin + months(as.double(date))) %>%
  mutate(decade_start = floor_date(as_date(month_start), years(10))) %>%
  index_by(decade = decade_start) %>%
  summarise(mean_s = mean(spots)) %>%  # Mean for decade
  ggplot(aes(decade, mean_s)) +        # Plot means
  geom_point() +                       # Scatterplot
  geom_smooth() +                      # Smoother
  ylab("Sunspots: Mean by Decade")     # Label
)
```

[image]